# Finding the amount of equal elements in the beginning of a list

Tags: python, list, indexing

Given a list in python, I would like to find how many equal elements are in the beginning of the list.

Example input:

```
x1 = ['a','a','b','c','a','a','a','c']
x2 = [1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 8]
x3 = ['foo','bar','foobar']
```

Some magical function (or a one liner) would output:

```
f(x1) = 2 # There are 2 'a' values in the beginning.
f(x2) = 3 # There are 3 1-values in the beginning.
f(x3) = 1 # Only 1 'foo' in beginning.
```

If I do:

```
sum([1 if x=='a' else 0 for x in x1])
```

I just get the number of occurrences of 'a' in x1, not the number of leading values in a row. Would be nice to have a one liner which doesn't need to know the first value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`itertools.groupby` can help ...

```
from itertools import groupby

def f(lst):
    if_empty = ('ignored_key', ())
    k, v = next(groupby(lst), if_empty)
    return sum(1 for _ in v)
```

And of course we can turn this into a 1-liner (sans the import):

```
sum(1 for _ in next(groupby(lst), ('ignored', ()))[1])
```

But I wouldn't really recommend it.

---

demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> 
>>> def f(lst):
...     if_empty = ('ignored_key', ())
...     k, v = next(groupby(lst), if_empty)
...     return sum(1 for _ in v)
... 
>>> f(x1)
2
>>> f(x2)
3
>>> f(x3)
1
>>> f([])
0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile).

```
import itertools

xs = [1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 8]

sum(1 for _ in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x == xs[0], xs))
```

In a function:

```
def count_first(iterable):
    i = iter(iterable)
    first = next(i)
    return 1 + sum(1 for _ in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x == first, i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is better check the first occurrence of something that is not equal to the first value:

```
x1 = ['a','a','b','c','a','a','a','c']
x2 = [1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 8]
x3 = ['foo','bar','foobar']
x4 = []
x5 = [1,1,1,1,1,1]

def f(x):
    pos = -1
    for pos,a in enumerate(x):
        if a!=x[0]:
            return pos
    return pos+1


print(f(x1))
print(f(x2))
print(f(x3))
print(f(x4))
print(f(x5))

2
3
1
0
6
```

Comment: Neat and simple. Thanks.